# Spring SAML quick start: Bean property 'signMetadata' is not writable or has an invalid setter method

Tags: spring-security

I am attempting to go through the Spring Security SAML Quick Start at:
http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html

I've gone through the four steps listed, done the two simple edits to  sample/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/securityContext.xml, and attempt to start the app as described in step 5.

I receive this error:

```
Bean property 'signMetadata' is not writable or has an invalid setter method.
Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

I have only changed the few lines of XML as described in the QuickStart.

That section of the relevant file looks like this:

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
        <property name="entityId" value="urn:test:chazlarson:waconia" />
        <property name="signMetadata" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

compared to the QuickStart's suggestion of:

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
        <property name="entityId" value="replaceWithUniqueIdentifier"/>
        <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
        </bean>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

What have I missed?  I am sure this is simple, but I've gone through this simple process on two different machines with the same result.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try this example?

```
<bean id="metadataGeneratorFilter" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGeneratorFilter">
<constructor-arg>
    <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataGenerator">
        <property name="entityId" value="replaceWithUniqueIdentifier"/>
        <property name="extendedMetadata">
            <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
                <property name="signMetadata" value="false"/>
                <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="true"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
</constructor-arg></bean>
```

I looked into MetadataGenerator class and there is no property signMetadata.
I would recommend you to follow [this doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/current/reference/html/chapter-quick-start.html)

Comment: It appears that the version of the doc I was following and the one you link to differ only in that "extendedMetadata" property.  I'll give this a try.  Thanks.